# how to allow negative value in debit/credit in OpenERP(odoo V16)?

Tags: odoo-16

I need to input negative value in debit/credit in odoo, version16, the source code as below:

source file: /addons/account/account_move_line.py

fields:

```
debit = fields.Monetary(
    string='Debit',
    compute='_compute_debit_credit', inverse='_inverse_debit', store=True, precompute=True,
    currency_field='company_currency_id',
)
credit = fields.Monetary(
    string='Credit',
    compute='_compute_debit_credit', inverse='_inverse_credit', store=True, precompute=True,
    currency_field='company_currency_id',
)
balance = fields.Monetary(
    string='Balance',
    compute='_compute_balance', store=True, readonly=False, precompute=True,
    currency_field='company_currency_id',
)
```

logic code:

## it prevent negative value from this function,

```
@api.depends('balance', 'move_id.is_storno')
def _compute_debit_credit(self):
    for line in self:
        if not line.is_storno:
            line.debit = line.balance if line.balance > 0.0 else 0.0
            line.credit = -line.balance if line.balance < 0.0 else 0.0
        else:
            line.debit = line.balance if line.balance < 0.0 else 0.0
            line.credit = -line.balance if line.balance > 0.0 else 0.0
```

also the inverse function:

```
@api.onchange('debit')
def _inverse_debit(self):
    for line in self:
        if line.debit:
            line.credit = 0
        line.balance = line.debit - line.credit

@api.onchange('credit')
def _inverse_credit(self):
    for line in self:
        if line.credit:
            line.debit = 0
        line.balance = line.debit - line.credit
```

I revised above code as below, firstly ,set fields "debit, credit, balance" the default=0 to avoid null error,then remove all code from above function, full code as below:

```
debit = fields.Monetary(
    string='Debit',
    compute='_compute_debit_credit', inverse='_inverse_debit', store=True, precompute=True,
    currency_field='company_currency_id', default=0
)
credit = fields.Monetary(
    string='Credit',
    compute='_compute_debit_credit', inverse='_inverse_credit', store=True, precompute=True,
    currency_field='company_currency_id', default=0
)
balance = fields.Monetary(
    string='Balance',
    compute='_compute_balance', store=True, readonly=False, precompute=True,
    currency_field='company_currency_id', default=0
)



@api.onchange('debit')
def _inverse_debit(self):
    pass

@api.onchange('credit')
def _inverse_credit(self):
    pass

@api.depends('balance', 'move_id.is_storno')
def _compute_debit_credit(self):
    pass

@api.depends('move_id')
def _compute_balance(self):
    self.balance = self.debit - self.credit
```

but it cannot work, after the modification, I can successfully input negative value, but when click the "post" button, all value become 0,
how to revise the code to have it work properly? thanks advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That feature it's available already in Odoo 16. You just need to activate Storno Accounting on your Company Settings and you could have negative accounting out-of-the-box